# How can I use CLAPACK,BLAS or LAPACK in a mex file?

Tags: mex, lapack, blas

I am having trouble writing a MEX file in MATLAB that can perform a simple linear operation such as taking the inverse of a matrix. I have successfully managed to take the inverse of a matrix using Visual Studio 2010 and have successfully created a MEX file hence the only thing I am having trouble is getting these two concepts together. I have tried to compile a MEX example code that I got from the MathWorks site but with no luck.

Here is what I have tried,

1. Saved the file (renamed it) I got from MathWorks as .c extension and then tried to compile it in MATLAB got:

   > Creating library C:\Users\CIT\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_bKHjrl\templib.x
   >   and object C:\Users\CIT\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_bKHjrl\templib.exp 
   >   eko1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgesv referenced
   >   in function mexFunction  eko1.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 1
   >   unresolved externals
2. Also I tried to compile it as a .cpp file however an error occurred because it didnt recognize the memcpy function.
3. Since these didn't work I wrote my own program that used the subroutines dgetrf and dgetri from the LAPACK library however an error occured:

   > c:\users\cit\documents\matlab\f2c.h(16) : error C2371: 'complex' :
   >   redefinition; different basic types 
   >           C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\extern\include\lapack.h(39) : see declaration of 'complex'  c:\users\cit\documents\matlab\f2c.h(17)
   >   : error C2371: 'doublecomplex' : redefinition; different basic types 
   >           C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\extern\include\lapack.h(40) : see declaration of 'doublecomplex'  eko2.cpp(29) : error C2057:
   >   expected constant expression  eko2.cpp(29) : error C2466: cannot
   >   allocate an array of constant size 0  eko2.cpp(29) : error C2133:
   >   'ipiv' : unknown size  eko2.cpp(33) : error C2664: 'dgetrf' : cannot
   >   convert parameter 1 from 'integer *' to 'ptrdiff_t *' 
   >           Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast  eko2.cpp(34) :
   >   error C2664: 'dgetri' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'integer *' to
   >   'ptrdiff_t *' 
   >           Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Any help you guys give me would be extremely appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to see what you've tried, it's hard to tell, but... in order to properly compile a mex file in matlab that depends on other libraries, you need to specify those libraries in the compile command.  Use `mex filename.c -v -l*libraryname*.lib`.  The -l switch indicates to the compiler that you are specifying a library that you want to include.  If this library is not found, I would include the full path to the library in the command. I hope that provides you with some assistance.  Using this methodology has been successful for me.